# Is there a C# a list-like data structure that does not interact with .NET mono GC?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, unity-game-engine

Is there a C# a list-like data structure that does not interact with Unity 3.5/4 .NET mono GC?

I know C# structs behave like scope variables in Unity and are not controlled via GC. I wonder if there is any free from GC if possible `IEnumerable` compatible List-like structure - with ability to filter, add elements into it and remove from it?

Comment: Main idea is to get a List alike item that would delete itself on going out from scope.

Comment: Not sure if I follow: you mean you want to create a list object that is _not_ collected by the GC? EDIT: Or do you mean that items in the list would be automatically removed from that list once nothing else is referencing them?

Comment: So you want something that will delete itself when it goes out of scope, but that isn't garbage collected when it's no longer useful?  Isn't that exactly what the GC is for?

Comment: @Bobson and ChrisSinclair I *think* the goal here is to reduce/eliminate GC managed allocations in order to prevent pauses caused by the collection.  This is not uncommon in games, where a hiccup will occur due to too much memory pressure on the GC.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You could write an list-like wrapper around a Memory Mapped File, I guess.

Comment: The it doesn't address the OP's question directly, but Unity has a [little writeup](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html) on memory management.  Nothing Unity specific, more a general GC overview.

Answer (score 3):

When using .NET, any object which is "growable" are going to be controlled by the GC, as it will need to have dynamic allocations.

If you the size is always small, you could potentially create a "collection" type wrapping a pointer from [stackalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to simulate this, but it's not going to behave like a normal list.

Answer (score 2):

One way of preventing a lot of allocations/deallocations and therefore causing the GC to run is to use a pool. This is where you allocate a certain number of objects, and then keep them allocated.

When you need a new object, you just take an unused one from the pool.  You don't delete objects, you just mark them as unused.

See also this post: [Should I use Pools for particles if i forced to re-init every particle every time i create them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387615/should-i-use-pools-for-particles-if-i-forced-to-re-init-every-particle-every-tim)